# Java Chart library for OLAP

Tags: java, charts, olap

Is there any java chart library that supports OLAP data, like 
[ChartFX Olap](http://www.softwarefx.com/Extensions/filmsLarge.aspx?movieName=olapAxesLarge&movieWidth=749&movieHeight=565) or [Dundas Chart](http://www.dundas.com/Gallery/Chart/NET/index.aspx?Img=OLAP6) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display any data as a chart, it will need to be reduced to a 2D recordset - which is what OLAP gives you when you run an MDX query.

If you've got that 2D data, you can pass it to any chart/graph code really.

I used to use ASP to run the MDX, and write out XML. This was turned into a chart with client-side JavaScript. I wrote the lot myself and it was a nightmare! Use Google charts or Flot.

Comment: This makes no sense.  You could easily pass in 3D data to a 3d chart renderer, such as the one that created this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_3D_Bar_chart_control/SampleApp.jpg

Answer (score 3):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) or [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?group_id=102) would be my recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

It's currently only working with icCube Server but you can have a look at [Javascript Visualization Library](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/viz/doc/vizTutorials.html).

There are some examples of integration with Google Visualization, AmCharts and Protovis. Actually you can integrate this in any JS library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the obligatory google solves that answer: Google Charts.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

However, these will not be hosted on your system.  I'm also not sure they support post request types, so the amount of data you can send is limited to the size of a get request url.

Comment: double check license, it's under 100% google control and you can't make it work offline (please vote up :-) ) -> http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=277

Comment: -1 Telling people to use a web service to create charts when they ask for a library that can create charts is missing the point entirely.

Answer (score 0):

jCharts: http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/  is one I have used in the past.

Answer (score 0):

To echo what others have said, yes, the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) may provide a lightweight solution along with a Java wrapper API like [charts4j](http://charts4j.googlecode.com) (disclaimer: I wrote [charts4j](http://charts4j.googlecode.com)). To see a complete listing of all Google Chart wrapper APIs, see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/web/useful-links-to-api-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at olap4j? http://www.olap4j.org/

Although not a charting library, you can use it to query OLAP cubes. The returned objects may be easier to manage.